# Why does blood seep from the eye of Le Chiffre in Casino Royale?

Tags: character, james-bond, casino-royale

**Movie Description:**

**Le Chiffre** is a villian in *Casino Royale* (2006). Le Chiffre is a financier of international terrorism in this movie.

In order to win the money back, Le Chiffre sets up and enters a high-stakes Texas hold 'em tournament at Casino Royale in Montenegro in an attempt to recoup his losses before his clients find out that their money has been misappropriated.

Bond is sent to make sure that Le Chiffre does not win back the money; if Le Chiffre is bankrupt, he will be forced to turn to MI6 for asylum, in exchange for information on his creditors and employers.

But during the last round of poker with Bond, Le Chiffre goes all in with the a full house of 66AAA and Bond has a straight flush 45678 and wins the hand and Le Chiffre starts bleeding from his eye.

**My Question:**

What is the reason behind the blood seeping from the eye of Le Chiffre?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[**CommanderBond.net**](http://commanderbond.net/3812/a-fragile-le-chiffre-in-casino-royale-says-mads-mikkelsen.html) has comments from Mads Mikkelsen from an interview.

> Mikkelsen also talks about the distinguishing feature of Le Chiffre–the scar above his eye. ‘The weeping blood is a disease. It is rare, but it’s like high blood pressure in certain situations will make people start bleeding from their nose, and occasionally through their eyes, which is kind of scary.’
>
> He explains that it worked especially well in Casino Royale‘s poker sequences between Bond and his character. ‘We liked the look of it because I was playing a lot of poker in this film and there is nothing more annoying than looking at a person that is unreadable because they only use one eye. It becomes blurry and unfocused and we really liked that detail.’

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chiffre) is a little more specific

> He suffers from **haemolacria**, which causes him to weep blood out of a damaged vessel in his left eye.